# pdf.js in asp.net mvc app is loading the pdf but not displaying it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

I'm trying to get the pdf.js viewer to work in an asp.net MVC 5 application but while the pdf is definitely being process, it is not being displayed.
Configuration:

Web browser and its version: Microsoft Edge (41.16299.15.0) and Chrome (64.0.3282)

Operating system and its version: Windows 10 (Version 1709 - 16299.125)

PDF.js version: 1.9.426

Steps to reproduce the problem:

- Include pdf.js in a asp.net mvc project
- Include the code from the Viewer.html into an Index.cshtml view and remove the body and head tags.
- Modify various path for the .js and .css
- If I click on the download button, the pdf file gets downloaded successfully.

What is the expected behavior?

Expected behaviour would be to display the pdf document.

What went wrong?

I'm not sure but it is definitely loading the pdf. It's just not displaying it.

- The Viewer is displaying correctly and so is the toolbar.
- I can see the number of pages in the pdf.
- I can see the progress bar when the pdf document is loading.
- If I provide an invalid pdf filename, it displays an error i.e. 'file not found'

I don't know if it's related, I'm getting a few errors and a lot of warnings:

**Error:**

```
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - http://localhost/PdfWeb/Scripts/pdf.js/web/
locale/locale.properties
```

**Warnings:**
    http://localhost/PdfWeb/Scripts/pdf.js/web/locale
    /locale.properties not found.

The locale.properties is definitely located in this location.

```
"en-ie" resource not found.
```

I've created a copy of en-UK and renamed it to en-ie but that this seem to have any effects.

I get dozens if not hundreds of 'undefined' errors. Here are a few of them:

```
#document_outline_label is undefined.
#attachments is undefined.
#attachments_label is undefined.
...
#page_scale_percent is undefined.
```

I've attached a few snapshots highlighting the fact that the pdf is definitely being loaded and processed but as you can see it is not displayed, nor is a preview generated when I'm trying to print it.

[image: Total Pages set in toolbar]

[image: Progress Bar, Progress Ring displayed when loading pdf]

[image: Print Preview displays blank pages]

[image: PDF Document not displayed]

I hope someone can help me with a) my issue where the pdf document is not being displayed and b) removing the error and the many warnings.

**UPDATE-1:**

I've partially figured out the problem. It is down to a `CSS` issue where the `viewerContainer` is not resized accordingly.

When I change the `viewerContainer` from:

```
<div id="viewerContainer" tabindex="0">
    <div id="viewer"></div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="viewerContainer" tabindex="0" style="width: 1000px; height:1000px">
    <div id="viewer"></div>
</div>
```

It displays the pdf document but the viewer/page is obviously not the correct size as it should be the same size as the toolbar and take the browser's remaining height as it does with the viewer.html sample provided.

[image]

I will check tomorrow whether there is a conflict in CSS with the default one provided with the ASP.NET MVC template but the fact that the viewer.html works would make me think that problem is not with the CSS provided by pdf.js.

While the above is partially sorted, I've noticed that the problem remains with the thumbnail view and printing is still displaying blank pages so there must be more than just the 'viewerContainer' that's affected.

Anyone's got any ideas on how I can resolve this problem?